# OnResume app becomes blank in Kotlin but works fine in Android Java

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity, onresume

I am migrating my app from Java to Kotlin. I have generated app with default Navigation drawer and renamed the Fragments associated with navigation drawer items.

These Fragments (Home, Settings, Notification)  contains some UI elements and one of them, HomeFragment contains a viewpager with five(5) views in it. I have implemented everything correctly and everything following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWY9Gba5oas&ab_channel=MobileApplicationTutorials) which works fine until I resume the app.

As soon as I press the home button and resume the app, I get blank screen but I can see actionbar/ toolbar properly.

**Pager adapter**

```
class PagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager):FragmentStatePagerAdapter(manager,BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT){
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 5;
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> OneFragment.newInstance()
            1 -> TwoFragment.newInstance()
            2 -> ThreeFragment.newInstance()
            3 -> FourFragment.newInstance()
            4 -> FiveFragment.newInstance()
            else -> OneFragment.newInstance()
        }
    }

    override fun setPrimaryItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
        super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, `object`)
    }
}
```

This is where I am attaching this viewpager in the HomeFragment. I have created the viewbind class following [this tutorial](https://android.jlelse.eu/viewbinding-in-fragments-the-clean-easy-way-2f0ce68aee22).

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     val pagerAdapter = PagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)
     binding?.homePager?.adapter = pagerAdapter
 }
```

I also get a lot of warnings -

1. ResourceType: Too many attribute references
2. RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
3. Skipping 55 frames

This app literally with just default code generated by android. except one recyclerview. No heavy UI operation going on becuase I am just passing a predefined string array in recyclerviewadapter.

Comment: And why you don't add the method implementations which you're complaining about?

Comment: @MartinZeitler hey thanks for the reply.... can you tell me what exactly you want to know? I can't share entire code.  If you are talking about the warnings then please ignore that, those are just warning my focus is on identifying the blank screen problem.